# enum is constant or const varibale or anything else ? getting error in the following code

Tags: c, enums, constants

```
#include<stdio.h>

typedef enum {a,b,c}key;

int main()
{
 key d=3;
 printf("%p\n,&a);
 printf("%p\n",&d);
 printf("%d\t %d\t %d\t %d\n",a,b,c,d);
 return 0;
}
```

When I try to get the address of either a or b or c
Compiler throws an error that lvalue required for unary &

I didn't get it because it's working for d of same type.
What's happening here ? are these constants or the const varibales assigned with values 0 1 and 2 by the compiler.
Beacause this kind of error we got for constants only.
Please help , I am new to C

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a,b,c are symbols for constant-integers within an enum. They're not variables to have an address. Hence & cannot be used here(which means only rvalue).

Comment: Anyway, They must be somewhere in memory or not ?

Comment: @Omkant Yes they are, but it isn't obvious where. Either they stored as numeric constants in a read-only part of the memory, or more likely, they are stored as part of the actual binary program code. For example if you write `if(something == a)`, you actually write `if(something == 0)`, which the compiler might translate into a single assembler instruction in the actual executable: "branch if zero". The constant a (value 0) is then part of the "branch if zero" instruction.

Comment: @Stark: It means enums are just the named constants which we provide for human readability right ? Otherwise it's same as 2,3,4 like integers

Comment: @Omkant They're in the compiler's memory. `a` is a constant value; it doesn't exist in your program's memory anywhere. `if(something == a)` is code ... it *does* exist in your program's memory. `key d` defines `d` to be a variable that also exists in memory.

Comment: @Omkant, yes they are. Which is why they don't have an address in the program. They're used for readability. Enumerations in C ease readability.

Comment: @JimBalter: Are eums like a ,b,c are tags ?

Comment: @Okrant No. `enum enumtag { ... }` provides a tag, just like `struct structtag { ... }`.

Answer (score 4):

Check out what an [enum](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/whbyts4t(v=vs.80).aspx) really is. It's a value. Remember if you don't initialize an enum list the first one is given the value of `0`.

Consider the boolean enum example:

```
typedef enum /* Declares an enumeration data type called BOOLEAN */
{
    false,     /* false = 0, true = 1 */
    true 
}BOOLEAN ;
```

So the enum "false" is 0. You can't take the address of 0, but if you make a "BOOLEAN" from this:

```
BOOLEAN something = false;
```

Now something is a variable and you can take the address of that.

Comment: you 'can' initialise an enum list.

Comment: @PrototypeStark - Yes... I didn't say you couldn't did I?

Answer (score 1):

The members of enums are constants (just like 3, 1000, or 'b'), hence can only be used as rvalues. They don't have any locations in memory.

But `d` is a variable whose value is one of enum members (not necessarily though). `d` has a well defined memory location and can be used as lvalue (we can take it's address, modify it etc).

Answer (score 0):

An `enum` is just like an integer type, with the added bonus of having a bunch of named literals. An enumeration comprises a set of named integer constant values.

From C standard C99. Section 6.7 Semantics, point 3:

> for an enumeration constant or typedef name, is the (only) declaration of the 
>       identifier.

so it just a declaration. no memory will be allocated.